# Can't connect to Mongo cluster as ReplicaSet, only as Standalone

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I created a MongoDB cluster with a PSA (Primary, Secondary, Arbiter) architecture with Google Cloud Platform.

I enabled authentication and set up keyfile on each replica (and arbiter).

I then opened port 27017 for external access once the authentication was in place.

After that I tried to connect to the cluster as shown on MongoDB doc, as below :

`mongodb://user:VeRyG00dPwD@primary_external_IP:27017,secondary_external_IP:27017,arbiter_external_IP:27017/my_db?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0`

This is not working and the connection is timed out.

I also tried with just the primary replica IP:

`mongodb://user:VeRyG00dPwD@primary_external_IP:27017/my_db?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0`

It didn't work either, connection timed out

Then I tried with just :

`mongodb://user:VeRyG00dPwD@ primary_external_IP:27017/admin`

And this worked just fine, but afaik, it's not supposed to work like this with a replicaSet. By the way, when I send data using that connection string, it's using only the primary node and not the secondary...

Is it a normal behavior for a replica set cluster ? Maybe I skipped a parameter when setting up but I don't know which.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Edit:

Here is the lines about the replication mode:

```
replication:
  replSetName: rs0
  enableMajorityReadConcern: false
```

Comment: Don't worry, that's not the real info, everything is false ;)
For the replica set name I just checked on the 3 node and everything is the same.
(I added the lines on the post's edit)

Comment: How could I do that ? I just created the cluster with the GCP helper and didn't run any command to set the nodes in ReplicaSet mod :/ (I just understood your comment about users, I removed the section in the post)

Comment: I think you can ust connect to any of the nodes, and run `rs.initiate()` and this will read the config files. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/. I'm removing comment to keep your post clean.

Comment: It did show primary secondary and arbiter on prompt ! and `rs.status` returns info

Comment: That output may be useful to include, so people here can see the replica set is running